# Where to install bulma-start through npm in project

Tags: npm, bulma

I have created a css folder in my public folder of my project. Is it handy to npm install bulma-start directly in the css folder? Currently project links to Bulma via CDN link but I want to install it on my local machine so the project can run it locally. Can you please recommend the best procedures for installing all dependancies correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bulma-start is bit different as compared to working with other npm packages so here are the steps I've followed to work with `bulma-start`.

- Create another folder say `temp`.
- Initiate npm package there by using `npm init`
- Install `bulma-start` by using `npm install bulma-start`.
- Copy paste all the files inside the `node-modules` to wherever you want to work with this project.
- Again do `npm install` to install the dependencies of bulma-start i.e. `bulma` etc.
- Feel free to delete `temp`.

> Is it handy to npm install bulma-start directly in the css folder?

`bulma-start` is a complete package to start working, this includes the whole js, sass, CSS folders and scripts to start working. So bulma-start should be considered as the parent folder of your project.